# How to make API call to Akamai source using curl from command line

Tags: api, curl, akamai

I am trying to make API call to Akamai dataStream source from command line. I have headers client_secret ,host ,access_token ,client_token,base url. Akamai developer doc,https://developer.akamai.com/legacy/introduction/Client_Auth.html    does not have good example.

Solid example to make API call to Akamai dataStream source form Linux systems would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find clients with authentication already implemented on their website
https://developer.akamai.com/legacy/introduction/Open_Source.html

Take a look at [egcurl](https://github.com/akamai/edgegrid-curl), a curl wrapper handling authentication.
Once configured following instructions on that page, you can call [DataStream APIs](https://developer.akamai.com/api/web_performance/datastream/v1.html).

Comment: I am able to make this call, similar way you mentioned. How ever their online docs are not that much helpful. I used  api-kickstart/examples/python/templete_script.py